# Understanding output from recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, pandas

I am trying to run the function `obtainingparams` recursively for 5 times. However, currently the output from my program is as follows, and I am actually unable to understand why the line `32323232` in the `while` loop at the end of the code is not being printed out after every set of `MATRIX`,`PARAMS`,`VALUES` output.

```
MATRIX [[ 1.          7.53869055  7.10409234 -0.2867544 ]
 [ 1.          7.53869055  7.10409234 -0.2867544 ]
 [ 1.          7.53869055  7.10409234 -0.2867544 ]
 ..., 
 [ 1.          0.43010753  0.43010753  0.09642396]]
PARAMS [  5.12077446   8.89859946 -10.26880411  -9.58965259]
VALUES [(0.5, 1.5, 206.59958540866882, array([  5.12077446,   8.89859946, -10.26880411,  -9.58965259]))]
MATRIX [[ 1.          3.14775472  2.54122406 -0.43709966]
 [ 1.          3.14775472  2.54122406 -0.43709966]
 [ 1.          3.14775472  2.54122406 -0.43709966]
 ...,
 [ 1.          0.25806447  0.25806428  0.07982733]]
PARAMS [ 4.90731466  4.41623398 -7.65250737 -6.01128351]
VALUES [(0.5, 1.5, 206.59958540866882, array([  5.12077446,   8.89859946, -10.26880411,  -9.58965259])), (0.7, 1.7, 206.46228694927203, array([ 4.90731466,  4.41623398, -7.65250737, -6.01128351]))]
```

And so on. `df` is a Dataframe.

```
values = []

def counted(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.called+= 1
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.called= 0
    wrapper.__name__= fn.__name__
    return wrapper


@counted   
def obtainingparams(self, df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals):
        global values
        no_of_bonds = df.shape[0]         
        yields = df['coupon'].values

        matrix_of_params = np.empty(shape=[1, 4])

        months_to_maturity_matrix = df.months_to_maturity.values

        count = 0
        for x, value in np.ndenumerate(months_to_maturity_matrix):
            if count < months_to_maturity_matrix.shape[0]:
                months_to_maturity_array = months_to_maturity_matrix[count]
                years_to_maturity_array = months_to_maturity_array/12
                newrow = [1, ((1-np.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_1))/years_to_maturity_array/tau_1), ((1-np.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_1))/years_to_maturity_array/tau_1)-np.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_1), ((1-np.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_2))/years_to_maturity_array/tau_2)-np.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_2)] 
                count = count + 1
                matrix_of_params = np.vstack([matrix_of_params, newrow])

        matrix_of_params = np.delete(matrix_of_params, (0), axis=0)  
        print('MATRIX', matrix_of_params)

        params = np.linalg.lstsq(matrix_of_params,yields)[0] 
        print('PARAMS', params)
        residuals = np.sqrt(((yields - matrix_of_params.dot(params))**2).sum())  
        tau_1 = tau_1 + 0.2 
        tau_2 = tau_2 + 0.2

        values.append((tau_1, tau_2, residuals, params))
        print('VALUES', values)

        while self.obtainingparams(df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals).called < 5:
            print('32323232')
            self.obtainingparams(df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals)
```

**Edit**: Calling `obtainingparams` which is a function within the `BondClass` Class:

```
tau_1 = 0.3
tau_2 = 1.3
BOND_OBJECT = BondClass.GeneralBondClass(price, coupon, coupon_frequecy, face_value, monthstomaturity, issue_date) 
residuals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
df1 = Exc.ExcelFileReader() #Read the Dataframe in from an Excel File
BOND_OBJECT.obtainingparams(df1, tau_1, tau_2, residuals)
```

Comment: Where do you first call `obtainingParams`?

Comment: @M.Shaw I've edited the question to show where I call it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never enter the while loop because in order to enter it you make the recursive call.  So before the test on `called` can be evaluated you are already recursing.  This code is not what you want:

```
while self.obtainingparams(df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals).called < 5:
```

It looks up `called` in the result of the function call rather than in the function itself.  Just replace it with:

```
while self.obtainingparams.called < 5:
```

and you should be just about there.

Answer (score 0):

```
while self.obtainingparams(df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals).called < 5:
    print('32323232')
    self.obtainingparams(df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals)
```

My first instinct is that the `self.obtainingparams().called` has to call `self.obtainingparams()` to get the `.called` property. In this way, you're calling the function recursively, but not able to pass into the while loop before the function is called, explaining the lack of output.

I would suggest that instead of using a contained variable to count recursion instances, use a variable in the enclosing scope that can be incremented on each call, and have the base case check this variable and `return` once it reaches the amount of recursion steps you want.

Example:

```
count = 0

def recurse():
    count += 1
    # Base case
    if count >= 5:
        return
    else:
        recurse()
```

Lastly, you need to have another look at what this line of code actually does:

```
self.obtainingparams(df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals).called
```

Your function `obtainingparams` doesn't actually return a value, but say it returned an `int`. This line would really be checking `int.called`, but `int` does not have an attribute named `called`. If you wanted to check the attribute of the function object, you would want to check `self.obtainingparams.called`, although in my opinion there are better ways to do what you're trying to do with this code.

Comment: Yes and furthermore, this code attempts to look up `called` on the **result**  of calling `obtainingparams` not the function itself.  So that would not work, even if `obtainingparams` did return a value - that value would not have a `called` attribute.